# Set Api.Controller.Json function to use the Global SerializerSettings

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

In ASP.NET Web API Controllers I'm using JsonResults like this:

```
return Json(data);
```

I've set in the WebApiConfig the global defaults as I found in many places suggested.

```
HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
```

I thought this would be make the settings be used, but it is not. To workaround it I'm calling:

```
return Json(data, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings);
```

This works fine, but am I missing something to make the Global Serialization Settings apply all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling Json(data), you are executing this overload - you can see it's creating a new instance of serializer settings

```
    protected internal JsonResult<T> Json<T>(T content)
    {
        return Json<T>(content, new JsonSerializerSettings());
    }
```

If you use one of ApiController methods that return a negotiated result, such as [ApiController.Ok](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314591(v=vs.118).aspx), e.g `return Ok(data)`, then the formatters are resolved from the global configuration and you'll see the behaviour you require.